# CollapsingToolbarLayout was not scrolling smooth

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am new to CollapsingToolbarLayout when i scroll my content was not scroll smoothly any one please help where i did wrong were below my layout,when i scrooll up it my layout was not scrolling smoothly

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fulldec_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"

            />




    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fulldectext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:text="The problem is not the problem. The problem is your attitude about the problem"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:gravity="center"

                />




        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullde_descriptiontect"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="More Links"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_one_t"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_two_t
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not scroll smoothly"? I ran your code and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Did you found the solution? I have the same issue.